# Saving to CoreData from 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' crashes when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view that contains images <1mb in size. When I scroll, I pull each image from my server and then save it to CoreData, unless it is already local (for purpose of a Cache).

Here is the function I use to save each image to core data...

```
// MARK: - Save Image to Core Data

func saveImageToCoreData(url: String,imageData: NSData) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
        if let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext as? NSManagedObjectContext {

            let privateMoc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
            privateMoc.parentContext = managedContext

            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Images",
                                                           inManagedObjectContext: privateMoc)
            let options = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                          insertIntoManagedObjectContext: privateMoc)

            options.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
            options.setValue(imageData, forKey: "imageData")

            privateMoc.performBlock({


                do {
                    try privateMoc.save()
                    print("Successfuly Saved an Image to Core Data.")
                    do {
                        try managedContext.save()
                    } catch {

                    }
                } catch {
                    // Failed to save
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

If I scroll slowly, it works fine. However, when this function is called by scrolling quickly and thus calling 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' many times, it gives me errors and crashes.

Error Example: `CoreData: error: (1555) UNIQUE constraint failed: ZIMAGES.Z_PK`

Is my Save function incorrect? Or perhaps there is an issue with setting up so many threads at once to perform a save function?

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your save function:
1. You are creating a private queue context for each image, which is not really a good idea. The better way is to create one single private queue context, and use it for saving all the images.
2. Do not call this save image function in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, since this delegate function will be called multiple times when scrolling the tableview up and down. Just do it somewhere else, like inside the download image completion call back.
3. Since CoreData is not thread safe, you **must** insert new image on the private context's thread instead of main thread. So you have to do this:

```
privateMoc.performBlock({
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Images", inManagedObjectContext: privateMoc)
    let options = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: privateMoc)
    options.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
    options.setValue(imageData, forKey: "imageData")
    do {
        try privateMoc.save()
        print("Successfuly Saved an Image to Core Data.")
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
        }
    } catch {
        // Failed to save
    }
})
```

After you making these three fixes, the issue should be resolved I believe.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use SDWebImage.